# What does this do? if(unsigned(x-dx)<unsigned(size))

Tags: c++, comparison, unsigned

I found this in a piece of code I am trying to understand. It is probably some clever trick, but I don't get it. When is

```
    unsigned(x-dx)<unsigned(size)
```

true? *x*, *dx*, and *size* are all *(signed) int*. From the context I guess, that x-dx should not be smaller than zero and not be larger than size. But I don't understand the **unsigned** trick.

Could someone explain it or tell where I can find more info about it?

thx in advance

Comment: Can you provide more context, otherwise the answers just going to be guessing which it looks like those are rolling in.

Comment: Be careful/specific with language tags.

Comment: The trick is that a negative number becomes a very large positive number when cast to `unsigned`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code determines if `x - dx` is in the range [`0` ... `size`): if `x - dx` is negative, it becomes a large positive value when cast to `unsigned`. *Large* in this context means, a value larger than any positive value of the type [`signed`] `int`. That is, the comparison

```
unsigned(x - dx) < unsigned(size)
```

is true if `x - dx` is non-negative and smaller than `size`.

Comment: @AlexD It's kind of correct. The range of negative signed numbers is half the size of the range of unsigned numbers. All negative numbers will be mapped to the top half of the range of unsigned numbers, so they're all larger than positive numbers.

Comment: @AlexD: the exact formula is't fun because it needs to treat some values special and there is no real guarantee that the underlying machine uses two's complement. I chnaged the explanation to clarify what I mean with _large_ (larger than any positive value of type `int`).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I certainly didn't guess about the behavior! However, I currently don't have easy access to the C++ standard to verify what section describes the behavior I'm describing.

Comment: @AndreyT: The situation that `unsigned(x - dx)` is smaller or equal to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` can only occur if `x - dx` is smaller than `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and this situation clearly cannot happen [in a correct program] as it would be undefined behavior (signed integer overflow).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: I'm pretty sure that the intention of the code is what I stated even without seeing any context! It is sort of a standard idiom. ... and with respect to the working papers: being a member of the C++ committee I'm well aware where to find them and I have access to the actual standards, too. Just not now on the mobile device I'm using.

Answer (score 4):

Saying `unsigned(anything)` is essentially a casting operation, very much line saying `(unsigned) anything`. It causes its argument to be treated as an unsigned number, which means it can only represent values greater than or equal to zero.

This code will behave oddly if x is less than dx. Instead of a negative number, the expression `unsigned(x - dx)` will become a large positive number.